# Python Script Saving/Copying into specific directory

Tags: python, directory, save, shutil, os.path

I'm attempting to write a script that will save a file in the given directory, but I'm getting a NotADirecotryError[WinError 267] whenever I run it. Any ideas or tips on what I may have done incorrectly?

````
import shutil
import os

src = 'C:\\Users\\SpecificUsername\\Pictures\\test.txt\'
dest = 'C:\\Users\\SpecificUsername\\Desktop'
files = os.listdir(src)

for file in files:
    shutil.copy(file, dest)

for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.copy(file,dest) ```
````

Comment: you probably want your paths as raw strings and you don't want `'\'` at the end. `src = r'C:\Users\SpecificUsername\Pictures\test.txt'` and `dest = r'C:\Users\SpecificUsername\Desktop'`. Now `src` is not a directory at all so why are you trying to `listdir`? it's a text file. Also as a side-note, please look into the `pathlib` module

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here:

1. You can just use forward slashes in the paths.
2. Your `src` is the `test.txt` file, and not a directory, so you cannot iterate over it using `os.listdir()`.
3. You can also merge the two loops together since they are looping over the same set of data.
4. `shutil.copy()` takes a file path as input, while what you are passing is a filename.

The following code should work and it also copies directories as is:

```
import shutil
import os

basepath = "C:/Users/SpecificUsername/"
src = "Pictures/"
dest = "Desktop/"
files = os.listdir(os.path.join(basepath, src))

for filename in files:
    filepath = os.path.join(basepath, src, filename)
    if (os.path.isfile(filepath)):
        print("File: " + filename)
        shutil.copy(filepath,dest)
    else:
        print("Dir: " + filename)
        shutil.copytree(filepath, os.path.join(dest, filename))
```

Hope it helps!